# Run time Error 1004 - Correct Syntax for Offset

Tags: excel, vba

My code inserts the new row after the text, but gives a run time 1004 error and does not insert textbox values from userform in the new row. I cannot figure out the correct syntax for using offset. Any help would be appreciated.

```
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

With ws
    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, "F").Value2 = TextBox1.Text Then
               Rows(i + 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
               .Cells("F" & Cells.Offset(1, 0).Row).Value2 = TextBox1.Text
               .Cells("J" & Cells.Offset(1, 0).Row).Value2 = TextBox2.Text
               .Cells("K" & Cells.Offset(1, 0).Row).Value2 = TextBox3.Text
               .Cells("O" & Cells.Offset(1, 0).Row).Value2 = TextBox4.Text
               Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: You're using .cells and cells... you need to be consistent with that, first and foremost, e.g., .range(.cells(r,c),.cells(r2,c2)) needs the same with statement referenced.  You also need to use the correct cells syntax, *Cells(Row,Column)*; you are using Range() references.

Comment: How about `.Cells(i + 1, "F").Value2 = ` and so on for J, K, O.

Comment: Also, if you're using .cells(r,c) format, you don't need offset, you can just .Cells( Row+1, Col).Value = ""

Comment: ^^^^ when using the unqualified `Cells` it is referring to all the cells on the active sheet and you cannot offset all the cells on a sheet it goes off the page.